# SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses - but there is no invalid addresses in the exception

Tags: jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send a message to multiple recipients. I'm doing pretty standard thing:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "my.smtp.host");

Session session = Session.getInstance(p);
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(origin));
msg.setReplyTo(new InternetAddress[]{ new InternetAddress(replyTo) });
for( String address : destinations ) {
    msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC, new InternetAddress(address));
}
msg.setSubject("foo");
msg.setText("bar");
msg.setSentDate(new Date());
Transport.send(msg);
```

Most times it works, a few times it doesn't. The exception I get is `SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses`. When I print the contents of the exception I get this:

```
-ivalid:[]
-valid unsent:[...@gmail.com, ...@hotmail.com, ...@live.com, ...]
-valid sent:null
```

Basically it says there is one or more invalid addresses and then it says there is no invalid address. Shouldn't the invalid addresses array have at least one email address?

**UPDATE**
The `SendFailedException` is caused by another exception with the following message:

> 451 4.3.0 <sender_email_address>: Temporary lookup failure

Maybe the invalid address in the message is not from any of the recipients but from the sender.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're [authenticating to your mail server](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#smtpauth), so it's probably not letting you [send to non-local addresses](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#norelay).  (Yes, the error message isn't very helpful in this case.)

Comment: The mail server doesn't require authentication. As I said, it works most of the time. It's always sending e-mails to outside addresses (about 20 recipients per message). I was hoping to find some wrong email address in the exception, but they seem quite ordinary (except for one @Gmail instead of @gmail). Anyway, if the invalid address array is empty I think the message shouldn't be "Invalid Addresses". Do you think it could be a bug in the error reporting?

Comment: You're probably going to need to look at the [full protocol trace](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) to see what's really going wrong.

Comment: I still didn't enable debugging, but I updated the question with more info.

Comment: Yes, it looks like the problem is with the sender address, and the problem is on the server.